# wp_handle_upload - specified file failed upload test

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, uploads

I'm using the `wp_handle_upload()` function to create a plugin that will give to the users the ability to upload files from front-end using ajax. I've solved an issue relative to an error in the syntax, now while I'm debugging the code I get this error from the function: `specified file failed upload test`. I don't know what's wrong with the code, can anyone help me?

PHP

```
  public function upload_form( $attr, $content = null )
  {
    ob_start();
    ?>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" name="imageFile" class="custom-file-input" id="imageFile" accept="image/*">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="imageFile">Choose file</label>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="imageMessage" name="message"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="process-upload"><?php _e('Salva'); ?></button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="cancel-upload"><?php _e('Annulla'); ?></button>
      </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
  }

  public function process_upload()
  {
    // $file = array(
    //   'name' => $_FILES['imageFile']['name'],
    //   'type' => $_FILES['imagefile']['type'],
    //   'tmp_name' => $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'],
    //   'size' => $_FILES['imageFile']['size'],
    //   'error' => $_FILES['imageFile']['error'],
    // );

    $upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['imagefile'] , array( 'test_form' => false ) );

    var_dump($upload);

  }
```

in my js script I have this code: 
NB: on the form I've specified the `enctype` and the POST method

```
$('#process-upload').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('action', 'new_message');
      data.append('imageFile', $('#imageFile').prop('files')[0] );
      data.append('message', $('#imageMessage').val() );

      $.ajax({
        url: wpu.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          window.alert('Done!');
        }
      });

    });
```

HTML form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" name="imageFile" class="custom-file-input" id="imageFile" accept="image/*">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="imageFile">Choose file</label>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="imageMessage" name="message"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="process-upload"><?php _e('Save'); ?></button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="cancel-upload"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `wp_handle_upload` is the function you want? What about `media_handle_upload`? What kind of file are you trying to upload and which mimetype is it? You presented the code for `process_upload` but there's no information about how it's called or connected up to be run. Also the documentation explicitly states the `action` parameter must match the action in the submission, but no action parameter is given to `wp_handle_upload`? Please edit your question using the edit link under the tags to include this info ( even if the answer is I don't know )

Comment: @TomJNowell read the question with attention, in the js code, the action parameter is appended to the form data and is the same I've used in my wp_ajax_  add_action function. I've found the problem and it was related to `$('#imageFile').prop('files')[0]` I don't know why but the file was not readed and I changed it to `$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]` and now all is working fine. About the `media_handle_upload` I don't know the difference between the function I used and the one you suggested.